# NSURLCache not used by NSURLConnection / AFNetworkingOperation

Tags: ios, ios6, afnetworking, nsurlcache

When I start a request with the `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` policy I expect to get the result from the `NSURLCache` if any, no matter how old it is. However, the system always tries to reach the server the request points to and returns an error if the server doesn't answer.

I use the `UIImageView` category of `AFNetworking` for the request.

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0];
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
NSLog(@"[%@] %@", request.URL, [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request]); // this returns an instance of NSCachedURLResponse!
[self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    __typeof(weakSelf) self = weakSelf;
    self.image = image;
} failure:NULL];
```

This will not set the image even if asking the NSURLCache directly will return a valid `NSCachedURLResponse`.

The app is running on iOS6 only, so there should be no problems with on-disk cache as far as I know?!

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue. Please refer this discussion on AFNetworking [github page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/566) for a workaround.